# Which specific optimization flags are responsible for optimizing out variables

Tags: c, debugging, gcc, gdb, compiler-optimization

I would like to specifically select optimizations flags to prevent `<optimized out>` variables (parameters) in gdb, without resorting to `-O0`.

My background is debugging glibc, which cannot be built with `-O0`, as it requires some sort of function inlining. However I can see this being useful in general, e.g. to enable useful debugging without totally killing performance.

According to `gcc -c -Q -O0 --help=optimizers`, the following 31 optimization flags are enabled by `-O1` in addition to the ones enabled at `-O0` (with gcc 5.3.1):

```
-fbranch-count-reg
-fcombine-stack-adjustments
-fcompare-elim
-fcprop-registers
-fdefer-pop
-fforward-propagate
-fguess-branch-probability
-fif-conversion
-fif-conversion2
-finline-functions-called-once
-fipa-profile
-fipa-pure-const
-fipa-reference
-fmove-loop-invariants
-fshrink-wrap
-fsplit-wide-types
-fssa-phiopt
-ftree-bit-ccp
-ftree-ccp
-ftree-ch
-ftree-copy-prop
-ftree-copyrename
-ftree-dce
-ftree-dominator-opts
-ftree-dse
-ftree-fre
-ftree-pta
-ftree-sink
-ftree-slsr
-ftree-sra
-ftree-ter
```

Note: I am aware of selective optimization / volatile as a manual fix, but I am looking for a more general solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not directly answering your question, but what you are probably after is `-Og`:

From the [GCC documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Optimize-Options.html):

> `-Og`
>
> Optimize debugging experience. `-Og` enables optimizations that do not interfere with debugging. It should be the optimization level of choice for the standard edit-compile-debug cycle, offering a reasonable level of optimization while maintaining fast compilation and a good debugging experience.

Using `--help=optimizers` on `-Og` and comparing it with what you get for `--help=optimizers` on `-O0` then gives you the answer to your question.

Comment: That really sounds like the solution. Unfortunately there are still some important `<optimized out>` remaining (less than with `-O1`). I was wondering why this option is not more popular and the universal answer is `-O0`.

Comment: @Zulan: If I were you I'd now find out the difference in flags for `Og` and `O1` (using `--help=optimizers`), then perhaps read about those flags (see the link in my answer) and simply try them one by one until I'd get what you need. And finally you might also like to come up with the out come of this work as an answer to your own question here. :-)

Comment: Global flags like `-Og` are not just the sum of individual optimization flags, so `--help=optimizers` doesn't give a complete answer. The option `-Og` is rather recent, reporting bugs about it (like those important `<optimized out>`) may help improve it.